# I have written the following code to find closest number in the B-Tree to "target"

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I have written the following code to find closest number in the tree to "target". However, it seems to only show the root node as the closest in the output despite other nodes having closer values.

```
def findClosestValueInBst(tree, target):
    return  helperFun(tree, target, float("-inf"))
    # Write your code here.

def helperFun(Node, target, closest):
                
        if Node:
            if abs(target - closest) > abs(Node.value - target):
                closest = Node.value
                                
        if Node.left:
            helperFun(Node.left, target, closest)
            
        if Node.right:
            helperFun(Node.right, target, closest)
        
        return closest  


class BST:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

Sample input:

```
{
  "target": 12,
  "tree": {
    "nodes": [
      {"id": "10", "left": "5", "right": "15", "value": 10},
      {"id": "15", "left": "13", "right": "22", "value": 15},
      {"id": "22", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 22},
      {"id": "13", "left": null, "right": "14", "value": 13},
      {"id": "14", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 14},
      {"id": "5", "left": "2", "right": "5-2", "value": 5},
      {"id": "5-2", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 5},
      {"id": "2", "left": "1", "right": null, "value": 2},
      {"id": "1", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 1}
    ],
    "root": "10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your recursive calls to `helperFun` throw away the value that they calculate, because your code does not assign the returned value to `closest`. So even if all three `if` tests are `True`, your code will only ever report the first result, because the rest of the function does not change the value of `closest`.

Comment: A B-tree is not the same concept as a binary tree. Also, a BST (as in your class name) is a specific type of binary tree, and you are not using that characteristic.

Comment: @BoarGules regarding the closest not being assigned, the code in first "if" closest = Node.value was meant for that. I was assuming that for each recursive call the first assignment code will run then based on the child nodes, the same function will run with the "closest" value. I have clearly misunderstood something.

Comment: Hi trincot. Thank you for your comment. Sorry should have tagged it as Binary Search tree. Regarding the property (left child smaller and right child larger) being not used. My idea was that since we are looking for closest, it is possible that a very large value on right might be farther than a smaller value on left.

Comment: You have 3 `if`-tests. Your code only assigns a value to `closest` in the first. Even if `Node.left` or `Node.right` evaluates to `True` there is nothing in your code that changes the initial value of `closest`. So the recursive calls, even if they are executed, have no effect. That analysis of your code corresponds exactly to your statement of the problem: *it seems to only show the root node as the closest*. Your code throws away the values returned by the recursive calls. So they have *no effect*.

Comment: Will you edit your question to make it about binary search tree, and not about "B-tree" (see  title) or a generic binary tree (see tag)?

Comment: Hey trincot. Have updated the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the fact that your binary tree is a binary *search* tree. You don't need to look at *each* node of the tree.

You could split the task into two parts:

1. Search for the greatest value that is not greater than the target
2. Search for the least value that is not less than the target

Both these tasks can be performed by a binary search, i.e. for each of these tasks, you need to only walk one path from root to a leaf

Finally take from these two values the one that is closest to the target.

Here is a set of functions you could use:

```
def findGreatestNotGreaterThan(node, target):
    best = float("-inf")
    while node:
        if node.value > target:
            node = node.left
        else:
            best = node.value
            node = node.right
    return best

def findLeastNotLessThan(node, target):
    best = float("inf")
    while node:
        if node.value < target:
            node = node.right
        else:
            best = node.value
            node = node.left
    return best

def findClosest(node, target):
    a = findGreatestNotGreaterThan(node, target)
    b = findLeastNotLessThan(node, target)
    return a if target - a < b - target else b
```

Example use:

```
import json

def fromjson(s):
    d = json.loads(s)
    nodes = { node["id"]: BST(node["value"]) for node in d["tree"]["nodes"] }
    for node in d["tree"]["nodes"]:
        if node["left"] is not None:
            nodes[node["id"]].left = nodes[node["left"]]
        if node["right"] is not None:
            nodes[node["id"]].right = nodes[node["right"]]
    return nodes[d["tree"]["root"]], d["target"]

root, target = fromjson("""{
  "target": 12,
  "tree": {
    "nodes": [
      {"id": "10", "left": "5", "right": "15", "value": 10},
      {"id": "15", "left": "13", "right": "22", "value": 15},
      {"id": "22", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 22},
      {"id": "13", "left": null, "right": "14", "value": 13},
      {"id": "14", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 14},
      {"id": "5", "left": "2", "right": "5-2", "value": 5},
      {"id": "5-2", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 5},
      {"id": "2", "left": "1", "right": null, "value": 2},
      {"id": "1", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 1}
    ],
    "root": "10"
  }
}""")

print(target, findClosest(root, target))   # 12 13
```